# Composer without composer.json

Tags: github, composer-php

Is possible to require project via composer from github which hasn't composer.json (etc. https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpcpd)?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11663559/how-to-install-jquery-with-composer for an example of that

Answer (score 1):

Actually this repository have a composer.json and an entry on packagist : https://packagist.org/packages/sebastian/phpcpd

so require it in your composer.json will just work. :)