# symfony2, composer and third party libraries

Tags: jquery, symfony, composer-php

I have several projects that have libraries like jQuery and I must say it's getting pretty annoying having to copy the libraries manually to `app/Resources/public` in Symfony2. Not just this but any other library dependency or plugin.

The closest I got is this question: [How to install jQuery with Composer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11663559/how-to-install-jquery-with-composer) but this installs it under `/vendor/` (which according to "best practices" it should be under something like app/Resources) then I tried using composer's `installer-paths` but also to no avail https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/2293.

What options are there left? Is there any way I can run `composer.phar update/install` and have jquery under Symfony2's `app/Resources/public` directory?

Comment: You could always just use a CDN link in your twig file, eg `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`. Otherwise, what you're after is a bundle containing the resources. These would get copied / linked into the `web` directory via assetic

Comment: I'd really like to have it download it once in chance there has to be offline debugging later (laptop with no wifi somewhere). I'm aware or I wouldn't have posted this question. It's not a show stopper because I can look for the file in other projects and copy it manually... but it's just so clumsy. I shouldn't have to do this manually for every dependency so I'm looking for solutions.

Comment: Try this one - https://packagist.org/packages/sonata-project/jquery-bundle

Comment: Looks more promising. But what you're trying to tell me is that I should probably create my own custom bundles with my custom dependencies in that case? Seems a little iffy, but it's so much better than doing it manually.

Comment: That's it and it's super easy. Just check out the (very minimal) code required in the [Sonata bundle](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonatajQueryBundle/tree/1.10.2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using composer, works better than I thought!

```
//composer.json
//for dev
"require-dev": {
    "jquery/jquery-dev": "1.9.1-dev"
},
//or for production
"require": {
    "jquery/jquery": "1.9.1",
},
"repositories": [
{
    "type": "package",
    "package":
    {
        "name": "jquery/jquery",
        "version": "1.9.1",
        "dist":    
        {   
            "url": "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js",
            "type": "file"
        }
    }
},
//Other 3rd party libraries
]
```

Then for twig something like:

```
{% block javascripts %}
    {% javascripts
        '%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/jquery/jquery/jquery.min.js' //for production
        '%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/jquery/jquery-dev/jquery.js' //or debugging
    %}
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
    {% endjavascripts %}
{% endblock %}
```