# Include jquery.js via composer

Tags: jquery, json, composer-php

I am trying to include `jquery.js` file in my project via composer.
Following is the code what I had written in `composer.json` which is been placed in the root directory of my project.

```
{

    "type": "package",
    "package": {
        "name": "jquery/jquery",
        "version": "1.7.2",
        "type": "jquery",
        "dist": {
          "url": "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js",
          "type": "file"
        }
    }
}
```

Now when I run this command in my Linux system
`$ composer install` I get following output:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev)
Nothing to install or update
Generating autoload files
```

And one `Vendor` was been auto-generated containing `autoload.php` file and `composer` director.

But I do not see any `jquery.js` file in my project directory?

How does this works? How can I get `jquery.js` included in my project directory via `composer.json`

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/a/16974088/3041606

Comment: Yes worked, thanks!  But I want to know.. how that vendor folder works which is been generated with my above code?

Comment: @prits it's because you still need to add `jquery/jquery` in the `require` section. Btw, I highly recommend *not* to use Composer for front-end dependencies. Use Bower (or BowerPHP) for this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to install jQuery with Composer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11663559/how-to-install-jquery-with-composer)

Answer (score 0):

You can find the jquery file in `composer/vendor/components/jquery/` directory

Answer (score 0):

You did not define what to include in your composer instance of course. You defined your project to be a composer package itself as it is also possible with composer. You would have a require section in your json or you would issue a composer require 'jquery/jquery' command on a command line in a filepath at the same place where your project thus this composer file is.