# How to use JQuery with php via composer?

Tags: php, jquery, composer-php

I am a true beginner with composer. I need to maintain an old PHP application with a lot of `<script type="text/javascript" src="../../jquery.min.js"></script>`. I would like to get rid of JQuery in the code base and rely on a package manager, so I discovered composer.

I wrote a basic `composer.json` then I naively wrote a test page while expecting to have JQuery loaded in my page.

```
<?php require_once 'vendor/autoload.php' ?>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Where is my JQuery?</title>
    <?php magic_to_get_jquery() ?> <!-- Is there any magic? -->
</head>
<body>
    <div id="test">Test</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I don't really understand what I should do to get JQuery in this test page.

Here my `composer.json`

```
{
    "name": "test/test",
    "require": {
        "components/jquery": "^3.3",
    },
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "John Doe",
            "email": "doe@example.com"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: It is often better to get JQuery from a CDN rather than store it on you local or live server

Comment: I know, but this is an intranet portal.

Comment: This [might help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11663559/how-to-install-jquery-with-composer) then

Comment: @RiggsFolly, not really :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use [scripts](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md) to copy jQuery assets to public directory after installing package by composer. Add something like this to your `composer.json`:

```
{
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "php -r \"copy('vendor/components/jquery/blob/master/jquery.min.js', 'public/assets/jquery.min.js');\""
        ]
    }
}
```

But you may be interested by using some tools for processing and publishing assets. Googling tools like "gulp" or "webpack" may give you some insight into this topic - you may be surprised how complicated may be using jQuery when you want to use all modern fronted stuff :).

Also PHP frameworks usually have some tools for publishing assets - if you're using one of them you may take a look at documentation, you may find more sophisticated and ready to use solution.

Answer (score 1):

composer update only download file in this repo:
https://github.com/components/jquery

So, I think there's no call function to load the js file, and you need to link it manually if you use composer. Or you can make the function yourself.